# Compiler gives error when struct is not initialized and if we try to access the property but not with variable

Tags: c#, .net, struct

I have one observation about struct. When I declare a property in Struct and if I don't initialize the Struct then it gives me the below error - "Use of unassigned local variable empStruct"

PSeduo Code-

```
struct EmpStruct
{
    private int firstNumber;
    public int FirstNumber
    {
        get { return firstNumber; }
        set { firstNumber = value; }
    }

    public int SecondNumber; 

}
```

Program.cs-

```
EmpStruct empStruct;
empStruct.FirstNumber = 5;
```

But when I declare public variable then the above code works.

```
EmpStruct empStruct;
empStruct.SecondNumber;
```

So my question is why compiler not gives error when i try to access variable.(In case of Class it will give the error).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a tremendous amount of confusion in this thread.

The principle is this: until all of the fields of an instance of a `struct` are definitely assigned, you can not invoke any properties or methods on the instance.

This is why your first block of code will not compile. You are accessing a property without definitely assigning all of the fields.

The second block of code compiles because it's okay to access a field without all of the fields being definitely assigned.

One way to definitely assign a `struct` is to say

```
EmpStruct empStruct = new EmpStruct();
```

This invokes the default parameterless constructor for `EmpStruct` which will definitely assign all of the fields.

The relevant section of the specification is §5.3 on Definite Assignment. And from the example in §11.3.8

> No instance member function (including the set accessors for the properties `X` and `Y`) can be called until all fields of the struct being constructed have been definitely assigned.

It would be more helpful (ahem, Eric Lippert!) if the compiler error message were along the lines of

> Use of not definitely assigned local variable `empStruct`.

Then it becomes clear what to search for the in the specification or on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=C%23+struct+definitely+assigned).

Now, note that you've defined a mutable struct. This is dangerous, and evil. You shouldn't do it. Instead, add a public constructor that lets you definitely assign `firstNumber` and `secondNumber`, and remove the public setter from `EmpStruct.FirstNumber`.

Answer (score 3):

**Regarding fields** C# language Specification says:

**10.5.4 Field initialization**

> The initial value of a field, whether it be a static field or an
>   instance field, is the default value (§5.2) of the field’s type. It is
>   not possible to observe the value of a field before this default
>   initialization has occurred, and a field is thus never “uninitialized

**11.3.4 Default values**

> However, since structs are value types that cannot be null, the
>   default value of a struct is the value produced by setting all value
>   type fields to their default value and all reference type fields to
>   null. The default value of a struct corresponds to the value returned
>   by the default constructor of the struct (§4.1.2).

PS: in case of class it gives error because reference type value by default is null

Comment: This is not relevant. It doesn't explain the reason for the error.

Comment: @Jason : it is relevant in terms of field and class cases, but not a property related error. Still can't find an answer in specification

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not relevant at all. The reason for the error has to do with the lack of definite assignment to `EmpStruct`. The sections from the specification that you quoted make no reference to definite assignment. See §5.3, and §11.3.8.

Comment: @Jason: my answer mainly regarding why `when I declare public variable then the above code works`, and `PS` is regarding why it is not working when used class instead of struct type. Nothing regarding property-related error

Comment: The bits you quoted from the specification do not explain why it's okay to access `SecondVariable` but not `FirstVariable`. That's the heart of this question.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, the code doesn't work because local variables have to be initialized before you can use them.  There is no "default" value; they must be initialized first.  You always have to initialize every local variable before you can use it.  For example:

```
EmpStruct empStruct = new EmpStruct();
empStruct.FirstNumber = 5;
```

Fields in a class don't have this same restriction.  If you don't explicitly initialize them, they will be automatically initialized with default values.  In effect, the runtime is automatically calling "new EmpStruct()" on the field in your class.  That's why your second example works.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Why would the compiler call `new EmpStruct` in the second block but not the first? This answer doesn't explain why there is a difference between the two blocks of code.

Comment: Ah... I think I had difficulty understanding the original question...  Thought he was talking about using a struct as a local variable vs. using a struct as a field.

Answer (score 1):

A few code samples might help clarify this better:

```
// This works because you assign both fields before accessing anything
EmpStruct empStruct;
empStruct.SecondNumber = 2;
empStruct.firstNumber = 1; // I made this public
empStruct.FirstNumber = 3;
Console.WriteLine(empStruct.FirstNumber);
Console.WriteLine(empStruct.SecondNumber);

// This fails because you can't use properties before assigning all the variables
EmpStruct empStruct;
empStruct.SecondNumber = 2;
empStruct.FirstNumber = 3;

// This works because you are only accessing a field that the compiler knows you've assigned
EmpStruct empStruct;
empStruct.SecondNumber = 2;
Console.WriteLine(empStruct.SecondNumber);

// This fails because you haven't assigned the field before it gets accessed.
EmpStruct empStruct;
Console.WriteLine(empStruct.SecondNumber);
```

The point is, the compiler knows exactly what will happen when you assign a field. But when you assign a property, that might access any number of other fields on the `struct`. The compiler doesn't know for sure. So it requires you to have all the fields assigned before you can access a property.