# How to use fields of a struct without assigning a value to them first?

Tags: c#, struct, point, definition

When defining a struct similar to System.Drawing.Point but with double instead of float: How to use X and Y without assigning a value to them first?

Example:

```
public struct PointD
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
}

static void Main()
{
    PointD testPointD;
    double d = testPointD.X; // CS0170: Use of possibly unassigned field 'X'
    
    
    System.Drawing.Point point;

    // Here I can use X without defining it first.
    // So I guess the struct is doing something to make that work?
    // Edit: This also doesn't work, but Visual Studio did not underline it,
    // my fault!
    int i = point.X;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried what you have posted?  It works fine.  A struct has all fields initialized by default to `default(T)`, which is usually `null` or `0`.

Comment: It only works if i do PointD test2 = new PointD();  but i'm trying to make the PointD exactly like Point. Point doesnt need the new in this case. (I have to switch from PointF do PointD, and don't like to have to rewrite 500 lines of code.)

Comment: Using the code `struct A { public float X; } class program { public static void Main(string[] args) { A b; b.X = 107; } }` works fine.  No initialization required.  Please post the error you are seeing.

Comment: In fact, the example on the MSDN Page "Using Structs" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taef578.aspx) explicitly includes an example which is titled "Declare a struct object without new"

Comment: That also works for me. What i'm trying to do is using X or Y without define it or use new on the struct (just like Point in my example code). Point seems to use public static readonly Point Empty; for this, but i don't know how to write that funktionality for myselfe.  edit: i want to be able to use the struct without new (that already works), but i also want do be able to use the x and y without definition like in Point (it is set to 0,0 without the new).

Comment: Mutable value types (`struct`) are considered evil by many. However, when you have them, you can initialize (assign) each field individually, but you can only *read* any one particular field once it has been assigned. That is the same for `System.Drawing.Point` and your struct, so your question is based on a wrong premise. However, note that `System.Drawing.Point` has its fields `private`; the `X` and `Y` are instance properties. It is still a mutable and evil struct, though.

Comment: @Mitch When the fields of a struct are accessible, you can *write* to each of them individually, but you cannot *read* one that has not been initialized. So `A a1; a1.X = 107;` is fine, but `A a2; int read = a2.X; /* illegal */` is a compile-time error.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Compiler gives error when struct is not initialized and if we try to access the property but not with variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529802/compiler-gives-error-when-struct-is-not-initialized-and-if-we-try-to-access-the). The accepted answer there is quite clear.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, granted, but that is no different from the operation of any struct in the NDP.

Comment: Here is the source to `System.Drawing.Point`, there is no magic: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Point.cs#a041be61667d4c9a.  Consider also that `System.Windows.Point` already uses `double`s for `X` and `Y`.

Comment: Remember that if `Point test;` is a **field of a class** it will automatically be initialized, just as if it had said `private Point test = default(Point);`. However, if `Point test;` is a **local variable of a method** that is not the case. You have to assign it (initialize) explicitly then. That would be the source of your confusion, I bet. Your own struct already has the same semantics as `System.Drawing.Point`, more or less.

Comment: Thanks for the source Mitch! I'm reading the source code trying to understand how this works right now.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I also want to thank you for your explanation above. I didn't understood it at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mistaken. The code you talked about woks just fine and there is no difference between PointF and your PointD:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyStruct ms = new MyStruct();
        this.Text = ms.p.X.ToString() + ms.d.X.ToString();

    }

    public struct PointD
    {
        public double X;
        public double Y;
    }

    public struct MyStruct
    {
        public PointF p;
        public PointD d;
    }
```

The title of form1 shows "00" as expected.

**Edit:**

Maybe you are wondering why you get a complier error when you try to use a struct directly, that was not created but do not get an error when you use an un-created struct within a struct. Or one within a struct within a struct within a struct within a struct..

Which should make it clear: The compiler doesn't follow these levels of nesting; it just flags things that are obvious to it, that is omissions within its direct scope.

Granted, this can be a nuisance but all in all I'm glad to be warned instead of being allowed to forget initialization.

Comment: You are using new, therefore p and d are defined automaticly. I'm trying to avoid new. You also only set the value, you are not reading the value without define it at first in Form1(). My aim is to be able to use PointD like Point. Without new and without define the value after PointD = example; But thanks for your time. Maybe i wasn't specific enouth.

Comment: Again: You are mistaken. I do not set __any__ values and, yes the MyStruct __must__ (even without the PointD member!!)) be created and no you couldn't use a Point a Pointf or even an int without making sure they assigned values.

Comment: You aren't setting the values first, i got that wrong, sorry. Also your code works without using new on the PointD directly.

Comment: Now i have to find out why i've got all that null exceptions after changing PointF to PointD. Thanks for the cognition.

Comment: I hope my edit gets things right; I had never wondered about it but it is not quite so obvious as I first had thought..

Comment: It looks like the compiler really tricked me. How can i delete my question ?

Comment: Don't delete it - it is not bad, it has been upvoted and we all are here to learn.. Actually you can't since it has answers.

Comment: Why almost anyone mentioned `System.Windows.Point`, which already uses `double`?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you know `System.Drawing.Point` (and probably `System.Drawing.PointF`), but, like I did the first time I needed to use those classes, you desired to have identical functionality BUT with `double` instead of `int` (or `float`).

Well, then I discovered `System.Windows.Point`, which uses `double` and works pretty much the same way, except it is defined in other .NET assembly (you need to add other reference).

By the way, there are also the very useful structs `System.Windows.Vector`, `System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D` and `System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Vector3D`. These include native vector arithmetics (you add a Vector to a Point and get another Point, you add two Vectors and get a new Vector, etc.) and the often-asked-for DotProduct and CrossProduct.

(The struct `System.Windows.Point` was mentioned in a comment but in such a "tangential" way considering the OP explicit need, that I found it deserved its own answer).